# request in another request called several times with rxJava and retrofit

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit, rx-java, android-mvvm

I'm using MVVM and rxJava and retrofit to send my request.
I have a bottom navigation view which has 5 fragments and in one of them, I have to send a request and after it, the response is delivered, I have to send another request to my server.
this is my ViewModel class :

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
val myFirstReqLiveData = MutableLiveData<myFirstReqModel>()
val mySecondReqLiveData = MutableLiveData<mySecondReqModel>()

    fun getFirstReq(token:String){

    val firstReqDisposable = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInterface()
        .getFirstReq(token)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).singleElement()
        .subscribe({
                it-> myFirstReqLiveData.value = it
        },{
            errorFirstReqLiveData.value = it
        },{

        })
    compositeDisposable.add(firstReqDisposable)

}

    fun getSecondReq(token:String){

    val secondReqDisposable = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInterface()
        .getSecondReq(token)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).singleElement()
        .subscribe({
                it-> mySecondReqLiveData.value = it
        },{
            errorSecondReqLiveData.value = it
        },{

        })
    compositeDisposable.add(SecondReqDisposable)

}

    override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    compositeDisposable.clear()
}

}
```

and in my fragment, I implement this way:

```
class FirstTabFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

        getFirstReq(myViewModel, token!!)
        observeFirstReq(myViewModel)
        observeFirstReqError(myViewModel)

        observeSecondReq(myViewModel)
        observeSecondReqError(myViewModel)
}

    fun getFirstReq(viewModel: MyViewModel, token: String) {
    viewModel.getFirstReq(token)
}

   fun observeFirstReq(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    viewModel.getFirstReqLiveData().observe(this, Observer { myFirstReqModel ->
   getSecondReq(myViewModel)
    }
   }

   fun getSecondReq(viewModel: MyViewModel, token: String) {
    viewModel.getSecondReq(token)
   }


    fun observeSecondReq(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    viewModel.getSecondReqLiveData().observe(this, Observer { mySecondReqModel ->
   //do some work with my data
    }
   }
```

my problem is when I switch my tabs, my second request called several times.

I think I assign a new subscribe every time i reopen my fragment, so it called several times.

how can I fix this issue?!

Comment: getFirstReqLiveData is getting notify evert time when you switch tab. due to which it is making API call for the second request. You have to wrap mutable live data into Event<T> and in fragment, you have to observe as EventObserver

Comment: @KishanMaurya can you explain more? I'm new to this and I don't know how to implement what you are saying

Comment: Please let me know if posted code work for you .. else share code, I will debug and let you know the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create below class

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false
        private set // Allow external read but not write

    /**
     * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
     */
    fun getContentIfNotHandled(): T? {
        return if (hasBeenHandled) {
            null
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            content
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
     */
    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

in Viewmodel change like this

```
val myFirstReqLiveData = MutableLiveData<Event<myFirstReqModel>>()
val mySecondReqLiveData = MutableLiveData<Event<mySecondReqModel>>()
```

in Fragment class

```
fun observeFirstReq(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    viewModel.getFirstReqLiveData().observe(this, EventObserver { myFirstReqModel ->
   getSecondReq(myViewModel)
    }
   }
```

change

```
it-> myFirstReqLiveData.value = it to 
it-> myFirstReqLiveData.value = Event(it)
```

try using this way, if this helps you.

Comment: can you share `EventObserver` class too?!

Comment: class EventObserver<T>(private val onEventUnhandledContent: (T) -> Unit) : Observer<Event<T>> {
    override fun onChanged(event: Event<T>?) {
        event?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let { value ->
            onEventUnhandledContent(value)
        }
    }
}

Comment: your welcome.. :)  :)
You can learn about the event and event observer on internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove `getSecondReq(myViewModel)` from observer and combine or chain your requests.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables

Something like this:

```
    val disposable = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInterface()
        .getFirstReq(token)
        .doOnError { errorFirstReqLiveData.value = it }
        .doOnNext { myFirstReqLiveData.value = it }
        .flatMap { t -> getSecondReq(token) }
        .doOnError { errorSecondReqLiveData.value = it }
        .doOnNext { mySecondReqLiveData.value = it }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).singleElement()
        .subscribe()
compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
```

Comment: I'm new in RxJava, I will read about it and use your answer in the future, thanks

Comment: @AzinNilchi you're welcome :) This link is really useful, I often check it to to see all the available options